# replacement on page.stdWrap in TYPO3 - typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I would like to make some replacement in whole html code generated by TYPO3. I am using stdWrap.replacement on page in typoscript (as below) however this seems not to replace final html code. At this stage some of the plugins are rendered as  instead of final code. How can I make use stdWrap.replacement on final html code delivered by TYPO3?

```
page.stdWrap.replacement {
    10 {
        search = #<a([^>]*)href="http:(\/\/[^>]*zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\.com[^>])#
        replace = <a$1href="$2
        useRegExp = 1
    }
```

}

Comment: have you tried a simple replace? you might have a wrong regexp and so the replacement finds nothing to replace. Another reason might be uncached parts of the page, but I think the `page.stdWrap` is done after replacing of the place holders for uncached parts.

Comment: Yes, replace itself works correct for example for standard contents like texts etc. However it does not work for some plugins like news because at the moment of replacing they are rendered in code as <!--INT_SCRIPT.183b587466b6302abd0346713fe23dc5--> so final html code is not beeing replaced in such a cases.

Comment: that's an usual marker for uncached content.

Comment: maybe you need to generate all links in another way than you use it so you do not need to replace anything later on. If I understand your replacement correct it will drop the http protocol (e.g. in favour for a default https). maybe you can enforce the usage of https at all?

Comment: My idea with that is kind of fallback - I will force links etc to be protocol agnostic however since there is lot of different plugins and page itself is very huge I would like to have also fallback solution that will check and make replacements in final html code of the website.

Comment: as you notice that late interference will slow down your pages. what have you configured as domain record, config.absRegfprefix, config.base? of cause you might need to do replacements in the data as far as there are stored links in the text with the wrong protocol or format.

Comment: Seems in my case I can use TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SC_OPTIONS']['tslib/class.tslib_fe.php']['hook_eofe'] which is executed after all content is in place already.